# Changing image styles in a node view (Drupal 7)

Tags: 7, nodes, media

In the node view of my custom content type I would like the image to stretch across the screen or at least be centered.  As can be seen in the below screenshot currently the image does not get resized and is left justified.  Would this be done through theming or some other means?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can manage image-styles under

> admin/config/media/image-styles

and then use these styles to show up in your node view. Settings can be found on the "Manage Display" tab of your content-type. There's a little gear on the right side of the field row...

Comment: I'd like to add that you should create an image style that has an "Scale" action not "Scale and Crop". And on the setting of that action, just set the Width to same value as your theme's content area, and leave the height blank. That will preserve the image's aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a styling question than a Drupal question, but you would probably want to do it in CSS with margin:auto.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this more with CSS than anything. If your body tag is already getting a class added to it based on the node type, you could do something like:

```
.page-nodetype img { width: 100%; }
```

The only thing that would make this hard is if Drupal is inserting the dimensions attributes into the HTML tag itself (e.g.: width="150"). That will override the CSS.

Or, just to center it:

```
.page-nodetype img { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
```